# Como separar apenas a primeira palavra de cada string de uma lista?

Tags: python, lista

Dado essa lista :

```
nomes = [ " Paulo Ricardo " , " Fabio Junior " , " Roberto Carlos " ]
```

Como faço para criar uma nova lista, separando o nome do sobrenome e só adicionando o nome sem o sobrenome nessa nova lista, utilizando a compreensão de listas, por favor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Código:

```
nomes = [" Paulo Ricardo ", " Fabio Junior ", " Roberto Carlos "]
n = [nome.strip().split(' ')[0] for nome in nomes]
print(n)
```

Resultado:

```
['Paulo', 'Fabio', 'Roberto']
```

Explicação:

`strip()` para tirar os espaços antes e depois de cada elemento, `split(' ')` para separar os elementos delimitando-os por um espaço, `[0]` para pegar o primeiro elemento do resultado do `split()`, no caso pega apenas o primeiro nome, `for` para iterar elemento a elemento de `nomes`, tudo isso dentro de uma list comprehension delimitada por `[]`.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/D4HtA6).

Comment: Nossa eu estava tentando lembrar o nome do método para tirar os espaços, e só lembrava de `trim()` rs

Comment: @wmsouza eu tb, lembrei graças a IDE pois quando eu digitei `tr` para escrever `trim` ele me sugeriu `strip` rsrs

Comment: obrigado , as vezes uma coisa simples se torna complicada , eu pensei em diversas coisas , mas não soube aplicar na prática .

Comment: Comentei na minha resposta a necessidade do `strip` nesse caso :D

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar, ao utilizar o `split` para separar as *strings* nos espaços em branco, não é necessário efetuar o `strip` antes quando não definido o separador como parâmetro.

Veja o que a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) diz:

> `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`
>
> *If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, **and the result will contain no empty strings** at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.*

Ou seja, ao fazer `var.split()` ele separará `var` em todos os espaços em branco e retornará apenas as partes que forem strings não vazias. Também, uma *micro-otimização* possível é definir o número máximo de separações na string. Como será de interesse apenas a primeira palavra da string, não há porque separá-la em todos os espaços; basta o primeiro. Assim:

```
primeiros_nomes = [nome.split(None, 1)[0] for nome in nomes]  # ['Paulo', 'Fabio', 'Roberto']
```

Ou até utilizar a função `map` para definir um gerador ao invés de criar outra lista:

```
def pegar_primeiro_nome(nome):
    return nome.split(None, 1)[0]

primeiros_nomes = map(pegar_primeiro_nome, nomes)

for nome in primeiros_nomes:
    print(nome)
```

Produzindo a saída:

```
Paulo
Fabio
Roberto
```

Comment: ótima resposta!